# Drupal 7. MimeMail странно кодирует поле From в base_64

Tags: drupal, mime, exim4

Есть сайт на Drupal 7 + CommerceKickstart. Установлены модули Mail System, Mime Mail. Проблема в том, что когда с сайта пользователям приходит письмо на восстановление пароля, поле "От" отображается в base64-кодировке, типа =?UTF-8?B?0JjQvdGC0LXRgNC90LXRgi3QvNCw0LPQsNC30LjQvSDQvNC+0LTQvdC+0Lkg0LY=?=

В каком направлении копать? Поигрался с настройками в Друпале - не помогает. Просто скрипты с сервера отправляют совершенно нормальные письма, без этого извращения.

PS. Используется функция mail() PHP, сервер отправляет через Exim4.

======

## Исходный вариант письма

```
Received: from mxfront6o.mail.yandex.net ([127.0.0.1])
    by mxfront6o.mail.yandex.net with LMTP id 7G2CMsFH
    for <real-ap@yandex.ru>; Thu, 4 Aug 2016 18:15:10 +0300
Received: from enneli.ru (enneli.ru [93.170.76.52])
    by mxfront6o.mail.yandex.net (nwsmtp/Yandex) with ESMTPS id 7S8go1ZhpC-F9KeVWJf;
    Thu, 04 Aug 2016 18:15:09 +0300
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits))
    (Client certificate not present)
Return-Path: zakaz@enneli.ru
X-Yandex-Front: mxfront6o.mail.yandex.net
X-Yandex-TimeMark: 1470323709
Authentication-Results: mxfront6o.mail.yandex.net; spf=pass (mxfront6o.mail.yandex.net: domain of enneli.ru designates 93.170.76.52 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=zakaz@enneli.ru
X-Yandex-Spam: 1
Received: from evlanova by enneli.ru with local (Exim 4.84_2)
    (envelope-from <zakaz@enneli.ru>)
    id 1bVKLa-0004mu-FO
    for real-ap@yandex.ru; Thu, 04 Aug 2016 18:14:10 +0300
To: real-ap@yandex.ru
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0KHQvNC10L3QsCDQu9C+0LPQuNC90LAg0LjQu9C4INC/0LDRgNC+0LvRjyDQtA==?=  =?UTF-8?B?0LvRjyByZWFsLWFwXzI3MzgyINC90LAg0YHQsNC50YLQtSDQmNC90YLQtdGA0L0=?=  =?UTF-8?B?0LXRgi3QvNCw0LPQsNC30LjQvSDQvNC+0LTQvdC+0Lkg0LbQtdC90YHQutC+0Lk=?=  =?UTF-8?B?INC+0LTQtdC20LTRiyDQuCDQsNC60YHQtdGB0YHRg9Cw0YDQvtCy?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 500:mimemail.module
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="364ac6c09d5b07247906b012e3c948d0b9dfaf631"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
X-Mailer: Drupal
Sender: =?UTF-8?B?Ij0/VVRGLTg/Qj8wSmpRdmRHQzBMWFJnTkM5MExYUmdpM1F2TkN3MExQUXNOQzM=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?MExqUXZTRFF2TkMrMExUUXZkQyswTGtnMExZPT89CiA9P1VURi04P0I/MExYUXY=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?ZEdCMExyUXZ0QzVJTkMrMExUUXRkQzIwTFRSaXlEUXVDRFFzTkM2MFlIUXRkR0I=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?MFlIUmc5Q3cwWUE9Pz0KID0/VVRGLTg/Qj8wTDdRc2c9PT89IiA8emFrYXpAZW4=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?bmVsaS5ydT4=?=
From: =?UTF-8?B?Ij0/VVRGLTg/Qj8wSmpRdmRHQzBMWFJnTkM5MExYUmdpM1F2TkN3MExQUXNOQzM=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?MExqUXZTRFF2TkMrMExUUXZkQyswTGtnMExZPT89CiA9P1VURi04P0I/MExYUXY=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?ZEdCMExyUXZ0QzVJTkMrMExUUXRkQzIwTFRSaXlEUXVDRFFzTkM2MFlIUXRkR0I=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?MFlIUmc5Q3cwWUE9Pz0KID0/VVRGLTg/Qj8wTDdRc2c9PT89IiA8emFrYXpAZW4=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?bmVsaS5ydT4=?=
Message-Id: <E1bVKLa-0004mu-FO@enneli.ru>
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 18:14:10 +0300
X-Yandex-Forward: 89db0c9208a4afaf33c7cac79265cf54

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--364ac6c09d5b07247906b012e3c948d0b9dfaf631
Content-Type:multipart/alternative;
 boundary="c26c4788f8ffea45fdcb1e3f33d6369cf0bd0fd00"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit


--c26c4788f8ffea45fdcb1e3f33d6369cf0bd0fd00
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition:inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

real-ap_27382,

Запрос на сброс пароля для вашего 
аккаунта был сделан на сайте 
Интернет-магазин модной женской одежды и 
аксессуаров.

Вы можете сейчас войти на сайт, кликнув на 
ссылку или скопировав и вставив её в 
браузер:

http://enneli.ru/user/reset/27382/1470323650/818lP8QbceYtD29gtXYSHhTjbau... 
[1]

Это одноразовая ссылка для входа и она 
перебросит Вас на страницу, где Вы сможете 
изменить пароль. Ссылка истекает через 1 
сутки и ничего не случится, если она не 
будет использована.

-- Команда сайта Интернет-магазин модной 
женской одежды и аксессуаров


[1] http://enneli.ru/user/reset/27382/1470323650/818lP8QbceYtD29gtXYSHhTjbauBihca9yMth04hQg4

--c26c4788f8ffea45fdcb1e3f33d6369cf0bd0fd00
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition:inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8Bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body id="mimemail-body">
    <div id="center">
      <div id="main">
        <p>real-ap_27382, </p>
<p>Запрос на сброс пароля для вашего аккаунта был сделан на сайте Интернет-магазин модной женской одежды и аксессуаров. </p>
<p>Вы можете сейчас войти на сайт, кликнув на ссылку или скопировав и вставив её в браузер: </p>
<p><a href="http://enneli.ru/user/reset/27382/1470323650/818lP8QbceYtD29gtXYSHhTjbauBihca9yMth04hQg4">http://enneli.ru/user/reset/27382/1470323650/818lP8QbceYtD29gtXYSHhTjbau...</a> </p>
<p>Это одноразовая ссылка для входа и она перебросит Вас на страницу, где Вы сможете изменить пароль. Ссылка истекает через 1 сутки и ничего не случится, если она не будет использована. </p>
<p>-- Команда сайта Интернет-магазин модной женской одежды и аксессуаров</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

--c26c4788f8ffea45fdcb1e3f33d6369cf0bd0fd00--

--364ac6c09d5b07247906b012e3c948d0b9dfaf631--
```

Comment: начните с просмотра в другом клиенте. возможно, имеет смысл приложить **исходный** текст письма.

Comment: Это не зависит, где смотришь - в браузерном интерфейсе mail/yandex или же в Thunderbird. А где взять исходный текст друпаловского письма которое автоматом генерится?

Comment: в клиенте. например, у веб-интерфейса яндекса это называется «свойства письма».

Comment: Приложил в исходном сообщении. (Только HTML-теги не отображаются у вас даже с "pre")

Answer (score 1):

как минимум и заголовок `sender` и заголовок `from` у вас закодированы **дважды**.

у меня есть под рукой простенький скрипт на *perl-е*, который раскодирует строки, закодированные согласно [rfc2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CAO
use Encode qw(decode);
$na=$#ARGV+1;
if($na==1) {print decode("MIME-Header","$ARGV[0]"),"\n"}
else {while (<>) { print decode("MIME-Header",$_); }}
```

ему можно передать закодированное или на *stdin*, или в качестве первого аргумента.

---

раскодируя, например, заголовок `sender`:

```
Sender: =?UTF-8?B?Ij0/VVRGLTg/Qj8wSmpRdmRHQzBMWFJnTkM5MExYUmdpM1F2TkN3MExQUXNOQzM=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?MExqUXZTRFF2TkMrMExUUXZkQyswTGtnMExZPT89CiA9P1VURi04P0I/MExYUXY=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?ZEdCMExyUXZ0QzVJTkMrMExUUXRkQzIwTFRSaXlEUXVDRFFzTkM2MFlIUXRkR0I=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?MFlIUmc5Q3cwWUE9Pz0KID0/VVRGLTg/Qj8wTDdRc2c9PT89IiA8emFrYXpAZW4=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?bmVsaS5ydT4=?=
```

получаем вместо текста:

```
Sender: "=?UTF-8?B?0JjQvdGC0LXRgNC90LXRgi3QvNCw0LPQsNC3
 0LjQvSDQvNC+0LTQvdC+0Lkg0LY=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?0LXQv
 dGB0LrQvtC5INC+0LTQtdC20LTRiyDQuCDQsNC60YHQtdGB
 0YHRg9Cw0YA=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?0L7Qsg==?=" <zakaz@en
 neli.ru>
```

аналогичная картина и с заголовком `from`.

---

т.е. **решением** в вашем случае будет нахождение того места в коде, формирующем письмо, в котором осуществляется **второе** (или первое, смотря откуда начинать подсчёт) кодирование. подозреваю, это происходит где-то на этапе подготовки письма перед вызовом функции `mail()`.

Comment: Ура, я решил проблему! См. выше мой ответ) Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно закодировано! Проблему я решил. Ларчик просто открывался, модуль всего лишь надо обновить Mime Mail. Это известный глюк в одной из версий:
№ 1908318 by jvieille, zionduc, bisonbleu | anrkaid: Sender is double encoded
https://www.drupal.org/node/1908318